# Django choice field unexpected behaviour (bug?)

Tags: django

I came across some weird behaviour in the migrations with Django 1.7. Is this a legitimate bug that should be reported?

In summary: I used a module level CHOICE field, which I initially referenced in one Model class. Next I made some alterations and referenced the CHOICE set in yet another Model class. In the migrations, this resulted not only in adding the new field, but also in altering the existing field, in such a way that the CHOICE set was no longer referenced.

The only way to resolve this, was through adding a duplicate CHOICE set (with a different name) and referencing the different CHOICE sets from the respective models.

initial code:

```
GRADE_CHOICES = zip(range(1, 7), range(1, 7))
# grade 1 to 6


class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    grade = models.IntegerField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES)
```

This works as expected. Next the model alterations:

```
GRADE_CHOICES = zip(range(1, 7), range(1, 7))


class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    grade = models.IntegerField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES)
    # ^ this line is added


class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    grade = models.IntegerField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES)
```

The resulting migrations add the field and choices to ModelA (as expected), but remove the choices from ModelB, reducing it to a mere IntegerField. This was the only way to fix this.

```
GRADE_CHOICES = zip(range(1, 7), range(1, 7))
GRADE_CHOICES_DUPLICATE = zip(range(1, 7), range(1, 7))
# Do Repeat Yourself


class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    grade = models.IntegerField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES)
    # ^ this line is added


class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    grade = models.IntegerField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES_DUPLICATE)
```

So the question is: is this behaviour unexpected. Anyone care to try and duplicate this?

edit, additionally:
The loss of the choice set is reflected as follows in the migrations:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='modelA',
        name='grade',
        field=models.IntegerField(choices=[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) ]),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='modelB',
        name='grade',
        field=models.IntegerField(),
    ),
]
```

The offending portion is the AlterField section, where the choices are now omitted. I understand that the database will be no different, but it does result in errors in the Django admin interface.

Comment: What do you mean, the migrations removed the choices from the field? You don't need migrations for a field with choices, they are not reflected in the db at all.

Comment: They seem to be reflected in the migrations though. I will update my question with the relevant portion of the last migration.

Comment: What errors do you get in the Admin?

Comment: @rnevius I would have to reproduce for the exact error, but this is what happens: The 'grade' field displays as an empty dropdown box [-----] and accepts no choices. I verified that the underlying database table was still properly filled. Upon trying to save the instance in the admin, the error is displayed that the 'grade' field is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator.

```
>>> GRADE_CHOICES = zip(range(1, 7), range(1, 7))
>>> print(GRADE_CHOICES)
<zip object at 0x7fd0dffd8308>
```

The first time the iterator is consumed (e.g. in your first model, or in the shell by calling list), you get the result you expected. The second time you consume the iterator, you get an empty list.

```
>>> print(list(GRADE_CHOICES))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)]
>>> print(list(GRADE_CHOICES))
[]
```

You can fix this by making GRADE_CHOICES a list in your models.

```
GRADE_CHOICES = list(zip(range(1, 7), range(1, 7)))
```

Comment: I do use Python3 and the problem was solved. Thanks @Alasdair